# Repeating a Capture Group 1 to 8 Times

Tags: regex

I have a sample string `t20g30x40m50q67z89` in which I am trying to first establish that the pattern of a `t` followed by any number of integers and any number of subsequent characters is followed by `x` followed by any number of integers exists and then use a capture group to find the next 1 to 8 patterns. My desired capture group result is (`m50q67z89`, which is a string of 3 patterns), but with the regex below I am only getting `z89` in the capture group with the message "A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration.".

```
t\d*.+?x\d*.([a-z]\d.){1,6}
```

https://regex101.com/r/jX8jZ2/2

Comment: [Will `t\d*.+?x\d*.((?:[a-z]\d.){1,6})` work for you?](https://regex101.com/r/jX8jZ2/5)

Comment: That works great - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

capture the group with the repetition

```
t\d*.+?x\d*.(([a-z]\d.){1,6})
```

now group 1 will be `m50q67z89` where group 2 is still `z89`